# Is there a floating point type constrained to range 0 to 1 in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am writing some convenience extensions to `UIColor`.
One of the initialisers expects a Float from a range of 0 to 1 to set transparency. 
I am looking for sort of equivalent to `UInt8` but on the float number range. The `UInt8` is an integer constrained to range 0 - 255. Is there a native type that would represent any **unsigned float** from range **0 to 1**?

Comment: For this would just use `UInt8` and make a convenience initializer that divides by 255

Comment: That would reduce the potential transparency values from 16 milion something to I don't even know how many but the problem is it would put the transparency onto a scale that doesn't feel natural.

Comment: Yeah, but you're likely dealing with 24bit colour, so the approximation will happen sooner or later.

Comment: If you're researching this, or following along on swift-evolution for its possible implementation (it's been discussed before), what you're describing is called a dependent type. I'm not aware of any widely used language that has this feature and it is very hard to implement in a general way. (Obviously a special case "fraction-of type" could be bolted onto the language, but I'm not aware of any common language that has that either.)

Comment: @AMomchilov The problem here isn't approximation. It's that "0.5" is more natural way to express "half" than 128. Or is it 127? Or is it 16,000 and something? Or... It's definitely a useful feature, I just don't know any common languages that offer it.

Comment: @RobNapier Yeah you're write. 0.5 is nicer ^_^ I really hope a good dependent type system gets put in. It'd be nice to have generic vectors whose dimensionality can be type checked.

Comment: And we are calling it UFloat<0..1>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can constraint this range. I would suggest asserting the parameters:

```
let allowedRange = 0.0...1.0
precondition(allowedRange.contains(red))
```

That indicates that that bad input is not allowed. Or throw an error that you can recover from elsewhere:

```
let allowedRange = 0.0...1.0
guard allowedRange.contains(red) else {
    throw NSError(domain: "YourDomain", code: 0, userInfo: [:])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a type that's a float constrained to [0-1] in Swift. But you could implement something that behaved that way.